# How to add editText.addTextChangedListener in TableLayout

Tags: android, cell, android-tablelayout, editing

My work environment is Eclipse heliose, Android 1.6

I have created a tableLayout with columns and rows added successfully, each cell has one textView and one EditText and I have a problem in accessing each cell and need to add addTextChangedListener to each editText inside the cell. So that I need to change the english text to indic text. Please suggest a solution

```
/**
 * Here we are going to define the grid The Grid has 1. grid's value in the
 * particular position 2.
 */

public void setGrid() {

    String questionNumber[] = null;

    Typeface fontface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/padmaa.ttf");
    /*
     * Table layout for the crossword elements
     */
    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.crosswordTableLayout);
    tableLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    tableLayout.setScrollContainer(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfGrid; i++) {
        /*
         * This table row params is used to set the layout params alone we
         * are not going to use this anywhere
         */
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tableRowParams.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
        tableRowParams.height = 30;
        tableRowParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

        /*
         * Defining the row element for the crossword
         */
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        tableRow.setPadding(1, 0, 0, 0);
        tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

        for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfGrid; j++) {

            /*
             * (1).Here we are defining headerTextView to set the clue
             * numbers. 
             * 2).columnEditText = a edit text view used to get the user
             * i/p data
             */
            TextView headerTextView = new TextView(this);
            columnEditText = new EditText(this);

            headerTextView.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
            headerTextView.setTextSize(10);
            headerTextView.setEnabled(false);
            headerTextView.setHeight(30);
            headerTextView.setWidth(10);
            headerTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            /* Override the edittext that has been created */
            columnEditText = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tablexml, null);
            columnEditText.setHeight(30);
            columnEditText.setWidth(25);
            /*
             * LinearLayout to arrange the two text view in a vertical
             * position
             */
            LinearLayout headerLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(tableRow.getContext());
            headerLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            headerLinearLayout.addView(headerTextView);

            /*
             * LinearLayout to arrange the first Linearlayout and Edit text
             * in a horizontal position
             */
            LinearLayout cellLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(tableRow.getContext());
            cellLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            cellLinearLayout.addView(headerLinearLayout);
            cellLinearLayout.addView(columnEditText);
            /*
             * Here we are setting the table's vertical border by some
             * workaround methods
             */
            cellLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
            /*
             * the column with complete black
             */
            if (cellValueArr[i][j] == null) {
                columnEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                headerTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                headerTextView.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                columnEditText.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                /*
                 * column with values and question numbers
                 */
                tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                if (quesNumArr[i][j] == null) {
                    columnEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    headerTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                } else if (quesNumArr[i][j] != null) {
                    /*
                     * column without question number
                     */
                    questionNumber = quesNumArr[i][j].split("~");
                    quesArrList.add(questionNumber[1]);
                    headerTextView.setText(questionNumber[1]);
                    headerTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    headerTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    columnEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }

            }
            columnEditText.setId(i);
            headerTextView.setId(i);

            /* add the linear layout to the row values */
            tableRow.addView(cellLinearLayout);

            int childCount = tableRow.getChildCount();
            System.out.println("Child Count ::" + childCount);

            LinearLayout linearChild = (LinearLayout) tableRow.getChildAt(columnEditText.getId());
            colText = (EditText) linearChild.getChildAt(1);
            System.out.println("GET ID " + linearChild.getChildAt(1).getId());

            colText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence seq, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (seq.length() > 0 & before == 0) {
                        final String charSequence = String.valueOf(seq);
                        final String engChar = String.valueOf(seq.charAt(seq.length() - 1));
                        println("GUJ :: currentlatin ===> " + engChar + " :: charSequence ==>" + seq);
                        // Method For Type Char
                        List softList = conv.getSoftKeyPressForChar(engChar, getApplicationContext(), seq);
                        charSeq = (String) softList.get(0);
                        Typeface fontface1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/padmaa.ttf");
                        colText.setTypeface(fontface1, Typeface.NORMAL);
                        colText.setText(charSeq);
                        // for placing the cursor position
                        colText.clearFocus();
                        colText.requestFocus();

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("AFTER TEXT CHANGE");
                }
            });

        }
        /* add the row values to the table layout */
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this programatically? Instead you can create a custom adapter for ListView having 1 edittext and textview for every item, it would easy at design and development part both.

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually we are creating a crossword app so i am doing like this.That crossword's font is in gujarati character.so need to change the text on users input.,its a kind of transliteration involved here.

Comment: That means you are having rows*cols screen, say for example 4*4

Comment: Yes,i have created cells like rows*cols position.here how can i get each and every cell values.first task is i am trying to insert the values in each cell later i need to get those values from every row.each cell value will be in gujarati fonts

Comment: Then the exact point is You can do the same task by just creating a custom adapter for GridView (having rows*cols), you can get/set values inside the EditText lying inside a particular rows and cols.

Comment: Initially we created with grid view only, but the we face problem in grid layout , when it scroll down the last two rows shows which is invisible initially gets swaped to someother rows thats y i tried working in tablelayout

Answer (score 0):

I haven't look through the code as a whole. But from my initial understanding, you can do it in any of these ways,

1. As somebody mentioned before, go for a gridview. I couldn't make much of that issue from the last comment to the question, but if its some scroll issue, you could have tried a layout-margin-bottom to some 5 dp, so that it doesn't get cropped (if that's what you meant)
2. Continuing with table-layout, create TextWatcher() once and add it sequentially in a loop. It might be good, if you can setId, or setTag for each element like, first editText gets name, "editText1", then, "editText2", so on. So in a loop, you can access each element based on loop index.